# What do I wrong while coding GORM API Unit Test?

Tags: unit-testing, go, go-gorm

A few days ago, I started learning Golang, PostgreSQL, and Unit tests.
I searched a lot of information about how to API unit test in GORM here and there.
I just tried to follow up Golang documentation (https://go.dev/src/net/http/httptest/example_test.go) and one of the StackOverflow posts (https://codeburst.io/unit-testing-for-rest-apis-in-go-86c70dada52d)

I am not sure I got this error message "undefined: RegisterTodoListRoutes".

```
handler := http.HandlerFunc(RegisterTodoListRoutes) in this line
```

My todolist-routes.go code is

```
package routes

import (
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "github.com/jiwanjeon/go-todolist/pkg/controllers"
)

var RegisterTodoListRoutes = func (router *mux.Router){
    router.HandleFunc("/todo/", controllers.CreateTodo).Methods("POST")
    router.HandleFunc("/todo/", controllers.GetTodo).Methods("GET")
    router.HandleFunc("/todo/{todoId}", controllers.GetTodoById).Methods("GET")
    router.HandleFunc("/todo/{todoId}", controllers.UpdateTodo).Methods("PUT")
    router.HandleFunc("/todo/{todoId}", controllers.DeleteTodo).Methods("DELETE")
    router.HandleFunc("/complete/{todoId}", controllers.CompleteTodo).Methods("PUT")
    router.HandleFunc("/incomplete/{todoId}", controllers.InCompleteTodo).Methods("PUT")
}
```

and my todolist-routes_test.go test code is

```
package routes_test

import (
    "net/http/httptest"
    "testing"
    "net/http"
    
)

func TestRegisterTodoListRoutes(t *testing.T) {
    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "/todo/", nil)
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatal(err)
    }
    rr := httptest.NewRecorder()
    handler := http.HandlerFunc(RegisterTodoListRoutes)

        handler.ServeHTTP(rr, req)

  // Check the status code is what we expect.
  if status := rr.Code; status != http.StatusOK {
      t.Errorf("handler returned wrong status code: got %v want %v",
          status, http.StatusOK)
    }
    
    expected := `[{"ID":46,"title":"test-title-console-check","last_name":"test-description-console-check", "conditions": true]`
    if rr.Body.String() != expected {
        t.Errorf("handler returned unexpected body: got %v want %v",
            rr.Body.String(), expected)
    }
}
```

Here is a link for todolist_routes.go : https://go.dev/play/p/XoVMbK7PnLu
this is for test code : https://go.dev/play/p/NddwrU5m6ss

I really appreciate your help!!

Edit 1] I found the reason why I got this error. When I remove _test above at package and run it. I got this error "cannot convert Routes (type func(*mux.Router)) to type http.HandlerFunc"

Comment: That's because you are using a different package name in the test file. When you do that you have to import the package you are testing and reference its identifiers with the package qualifier. If you don't want to do that, then simply use the same package name in the test files as you do in the non-test files.

Comment: https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Test_packages -- *"Test files that declare a package with the suffix "_test" will be compiled as a separate package, and then linked and run with the main test binary."*

Comment: @mkopriva First of all, thank you for pointing it out! Could you check my edit part please?

Comment: `http.HandlerFunc` is a type, to be more specific it is a function type, however it is not a function. And an expression of the form `T(x)` where `T` is a type and `x` is an expression, is called a type conversion. So your expression `http.HandlerFunc(RegisterTodoListRoutes)` is an attempt at converting the variable `RegisterTodoListRoutes` (which is of type `func(*mux.Router)`) to the type `http.HandlerFunc`. The problem you have is that the type `func(*mux.Router)` is simply NOT convertible to the type `http.HandlerFunc`.

Comment: The "what can be converted to what" rules are described here: https://go.dev/ref/spec#Conversions.

Comment: @mkopriva Thank you for your help! I am just getting started reading your link! :)

Comment: @mkopriva I think I cannot convert mux.Router to type http.HandlerFunc...

Comment: You cannot and you shouldn't. There is zero reasons for you to want to do that.

Comment: It is unclear to me what you are trying to do @jjw. Look at the blog article that you have linked, each test there is trying to test an individual handler. But your test, given its name, seems to try to test whether or not a set of "todo" handlers are registered with mux.Router. The two types of tests are very, very different. You should not copy one test pattern and try to force it on every test, especially not one that's incompatible with the pattern.